Adobe After Effects SDK plugin not showing
I have recently begun programming for after effects (I have a basic knowledge of programming principles)
I started using the Skeleton from the examples, tested out stuff and even changed it to make a fill effect.
Now when I try to upload the Mangler project, Visual Studio opens After effects with no problem but I can't find the Mangler Effect.
Couldn't find any errors related to the plugin in AE's log and when I try to launch it again with my Skeleton's version (Changed the name to Basics) it still works.
Also checked and the Mangler.aex file is created.
Any idea what is wrong here? I haven't changed a bit of the code :(
